# Angular bootstrap uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

How do I set `uib-typeahed` result to uppercase from HTML view only.
I don't care of any result from controller, but on the view it should be in uppercase.

Also, `uppercase` filter not working on it.
Here is [attached](https://plnkr.co/edit/gT0hoQIM2rlnXFWCGysf?p=preview) plunker.

Help me out,
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided by Ashish is good but if you want to *make the UI consistent*, you can [refer this approach](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4K6VVmz3wqkvXYAz)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected"
    uib-typeahead="state.toUpperCase() for state in states  | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
   class="form-control">
```

so that **the selected value is also in Uppercase** inside the input box

Comment: Wonderful...! I didn't know about this, and there is no reference like this...Thanks..
Also now we don't need `| uppercase` anymore.

Comment: @BHARGAV its a javascript function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PAEw4Vt6YVkELpD9GGw6?p=preview)

You need to use custom template for this using `typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"`

And add new custom template like this.

```
<a>
  <span ng-bind-html="match.label |uppercase"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't won't any extra efforts for just uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a css in your case to make the results in the view uppercase

```
.typeahead-demo .dropdown-menu {
  text-transform : uppercase;
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ni719u1pNCOVMiMfLQeL?p=preview

**Note: Have removed uppercase from your input element because that is not going to work.**

Comment: As I said, I want in HTML only. I do have other options too.